# How do I import my .xlsx into Squib (Ruby gem), and can I paste sample .rb files somewhere?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to import my .xlsx, but the directions for Squib seem to be directed at Linux users, whereas I have Windows. How do I import it?

Also, is there a way I can paste the sample card and deck files, then tweak them for personalization? If so, where would I put them?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried looking at their [Sample Code](https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/blob/master/samples/excel.rb). I don't understand what you mean about them being directed at Linux users as I do not see any reference to OS other than a warning about building native extensions which can always be an issue windows or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've figured that out and managed to paste the samples into the deck.rb and layout.yml files. How do I now run them in Ruby so that the output folder (i.e. the images) updates based on their new contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you copy and save the [sample](https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/blob/master/samples/excel.rb), you'll want to open up a command line prompt and change into your project directory. On Windows, it's Start > Run > cmd. Use `cd` to change directories.

For example, suppose your `deck.rb` is in `c:\mygames\cool-game`. Your command line would look something like this:

```
C:\Users\youruser> cd c:\mygames\cool-game
C:\mygames\coolgame> ruby deck.rb
C:\mygames\coolgame>
```

If nothing shows up and you get the prompt back, then the script ran without problem.

After that last command, the directory `_output` is created with your images.

(BTW I actually work mostly on Windows, so if they seem like they're for Linux that's entirely by accident. Perhaps you've never worked on the command line before, but trust me, the command line is a beautifully productive tool!)

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks so much for your response. I only have Kingsoft Spreadsheets and can't save as .xlsx, and .csv seems more complicated as it doesn't support multiple sheets. My original work is in Google Sheets, anyway, so I'm trying to apply your workaround, but I'm having some trouble. I think I have it all figured out until the last part, "# Call your Squib::Deck.new here... etc." Could you please explain that in layspeak? Thanks! Also, I'd be willing to write up a guide for nonprogrammers to use Squib, if you're interested (and if you can help me get it working!). Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I ran out of characters in the previous post, but your explanation worked very well—thank you! Another question: Am I just replacing the contents of deck.rb with that Google Sheets workaround, or should that be a separate file somewhere (and if so, what title/filetype)? As for the guide I mentioned, I posted a draft on Reddit and would be glad to turn it into a proper guide for people who have never used Ruby, as sort of a thank-you for helping me get this working and a contribution to the community. Let me know!

Comment: Sure, if you write up a guide I'll link to it. In fact, I'm thinking of starting a blog on the website and I'd be happy to have contributions like this one there. I don't know Kingsoft spreadsheets, but exporting CSV will probably be your best bet for now. The "# Call your Squib::Deck.new here... etc." - I'm not sure what you're referring to. Also: where's the draft on Reddit? I haven't been following Reddit.

Comment: Here's the beginning—I have to go in and fix/clarify some things and, of course, flesh it out once I get things working a little better: https://www.reddit.com/r/tabletopgamedesign/comments/3etquu/how_i_got_squib_ruby_dsl_for_deck_prototyping/ The 
"#Call..." is from the Gist you have linked; it's the last three lines (https://gist.github.com/pickfifteen/aeee73ec2ce162b0aee8). Should I just export my Google Sheet as a .csv manually and use that, then change all references to sample.xlsx to googlesheetfilename.csv?

Comment: Actually, if you have a few minutes, would you mind speaking to me on Google chat or some equivalent just to help me get this running? I'd really appreciate your time!—I know nothing about programming and have been trying to get this to work for three days, now. I'd be more than happy to write up the idiots' guide afterwards as a thank-you!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have time for a call. My best advice is to just keep at it. Keep simplifying what you're trying to do until you get something working, then build from there. And about the non-programmer label: you're editing code, so that already makes you a programmer :) For learning introductory programming stuff, places like codeacademy.com and codeschool.com are great too.

Comment: No problem, I think I have it working. Thanks for all your help. I'll let you know when there's a proper guide written and send a link.